# IOS old version check

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I am developing an IOS and AppleWatch application. These apps in one application. My application min IOS version is IOS 6.0. But min IOS version for AppleWatch code is IOS 9.0. I tested this code in IOS 6 device but this code block run. I want to not run this code block in IOS 6. I want to run in IOS 9.0. Please help.

```
.h 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_9_0
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
#endif

#if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_9_0
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject<WCSessionDelegate>{
#else
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject{
#endif

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL oneTimeSaved;

+(WatchConnectivityManager*)getInstance;

-(void)sharedDefaultsDataSave:(NSString*)params;
@end
```

---

```
.m

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        #if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_9_0
        //This code run IOS 9.0
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0") && NSClassFromString(@"WCSession")!=nil && [WCSession isSupported]) {
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];

        }

        #endif

    }
    /* finally return the object */

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Never use code to detect the iOS version, this is wrong. Just the whether the `WCSession` class is available should be enough.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you. Actually my problem is .h file. I updated my question added .h code. What should I do for this scenario.

Comment: The `#if` is a compiler directive, thus I will always use this code if you are compiling it with the iOS 9 SDK. You can therefor remove this.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** 
For the header you really need preprocessor directives (or consider switching to swift and use `@available`)

I think you are using the wrong directives though:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_9_0
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
#endif

#if defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_9_0
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject<WCSessionDelegate>{
#else
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject{
#endif
}
```

Please note, i replaced `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` with `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`

---

Don't use preprocessor directives in this scenario, it might go wrong and confuses the compiler

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        if (NSClassFromString(@"WCSession") && [WCSession isSupported]) { // [WCSession class] in iOS
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Will make sure the if block is only called, when WCSession is available, which is what I assume you want and is downwards compatible

Comment: Thank you for answer @MarkHim. Actually my problem is .h file. I updated my question added .h code. What should I do for this scenario. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @MarkHim. Thank you, I tried __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED and  __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED in IOS 6.0 but if condition return true :/. Is this normally?